# .Net MAUI GraphicsView not updating

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

Could someone please explain what am I doing wrong? I tested this on android only.
I created control with GraphicsView chart that takes progress property.

When page is loaded first time, control is drawn with empty progress, when I navigate away to another page and back, progress is drawn properly. I wanted to force Drawable to update when progress changes, but it doesn't work properly.

My control:

```
public partial class SunProgress : ContentView
{
    // other properies

    public static readonly BindableProperty ProgressProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Progress), typeof(float), typeof(SunProgress), propertyChanged: ProgressChanged);
    public float Progress
    {
        get => (float)GetValue(ProgressProperty);
        set => SetValue(ProgressProperty, value);
    }

    public SunProgress()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void ProgressChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = bindable as SunProgress;
        control.Chart.Progress = (float)newValue;
    }
}
```

Inside my control i have GraphicView:

```
<ContentView>
...
    <GraphicsView Grid.Row="0"
                  x:Name="ChartView"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  HeightRequest="150"
                  WidthRequest="150">
        <GraphicsView.Drawable>
            <controls:ProgressChart x:Name="Chart" />
        </GraphicsView.Drawable>
    </GraphicsView>
...
</ContentView>
```

My Progress chart:

```
public class ProgressChart : GraphicsView, IDrawable
{
    private float _progress;

    public float Progress
    {
        get => _progress;
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
            Invalidate(); // this call should force Drawable to redraw itself? 
        }
    }

    public Color Color { get; set; } = Colors.Orange;

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        // my drawing
    }
}
```

I also tried to inherit from BindableObject and bind SunProgress Progress to ProgressChart Progress but effect is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have combined two different object that is connected through the `Drawable` property. Also you have wrapped your `Drawable`/`GraphicsView` inside another `GraphicsView`(xaml). If I may speculate, when I look at the source code Invalidate invokes the Handler for each Invalidate and the events somehow get mixed up. Perhaps not the answer you where looking for. My suggestion is to have a clean `IDrawable` class, and use `Invalidate()` from your `ContentView`

```cs
public class ProgressChart : IDrawable
{
    private float _progress;

    public float Progress
    {
        get => _progress;
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
        }
    }

    public Color Color { get; set; } = Colors.Orange;

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        // my drawing
    }
}
```

```cs
public partial class SunProgress : ContentView
{
    // other properies

    public static readonly BindableProperty ProgressProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Progress), typeof(float), typeof(SunProgress), propertyChanged: ProgressChanged);
    public float Progress
    {
        get => (float)GetValue(ProgressProperty);
        set => SetValue(ProgressProperty, value);
    }

    public SunProgress()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void ProgressChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = bindable as SunProgress;
        control.Chart.Progress = (float)newValue;
        control.ChartView.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks a lot.
"Also you have wrapped your Drawable/GraphicsView inside another GraphicsView(xaml)"
I did that because when I used BindablePropery on my Drawable did not work, so I was looking for workaround.